# Equivalent of C++ std::setprecision(20) using printf in C

Tags: c++, c

I want to print doubles in decimal notation with full precision (but without extra zeros at the end of the number). In C++ I can use:

```
std::setprecision(20);
cout << d; // Here d is a double
```

What would be the equivalent C code using printf?

Comment: Possibly interesting: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "%.20g" specifier. g is IMHO usually better than f since it doesn't print trailing zeros, and handles large/small values sensibly (changing to e format).

Also note that with the "g" specifier, the precision (the "20" in this case) specifies the number of significant digits rather than the number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 8):

Format is typically: `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier`, so for example, `%.20f`

If you pass in `.*` rather than `.20`, you can pass in an arbitrary precision at run time *before* the decimal value.

NOTE: you can use `g` too, however you should note that in some cases, there will be a difference in the result (between `f` and `g` - due to the way that the precision is interpreted.)

The main question though is what do you need that kind of precision for? (double/floats are imprecise)...

Comment: The question specifically states "but without extra zeros at the end of the number". This solution will add trailing zeros to the string printed.

Comment: As long as you have space to store the whole number, just use `snprintf` and then strip the trailing zeros yourself...

Comment: @qbert220, I did say "for example", and I was talking primarily about precision, but I will ammend...

Comment: @qbert: "extra" zeroes is a rather meaningless terms. Extra compared to what? A reasonable interpretation is zeroes that do not correspond to bits in the memory representation of `double`

Comment: @MSalters - from the context of the question I understood it to mean trailing zeros. That is the behaviour of the c++ code the OP posted.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion raised by the question. What I ment there was avoid trailing zeros, and the %.20g format is perfect for this.

Comment: @KRao: PS. Consider than 17 significant digits is enough to recover the original value for IEEE 754 double binary->decimal->binary conversion, so "%.20g" will print some unnecessary characters, "%.17g" is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
printf("%.20f", d);
```

That should work.

Taken from [an online doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/), the more general format is:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

Go through [the link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) to read about each token in the format.